# How can one model squeezed states in 3D optical modelling software?

Tags: optics, simulations, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

I would like to model squeezed light and its evolution (such as when passing through lenses after being generated) using optics software such as OptiFDTD or ZEMAX. However, I don’t see any way to make such states…my plan was to simulate an Optical Parametric Amplifier or Oscillator to generate these states but I can’t seem to find any way to do that. Is there any way to generate squeezed states of light in a 3D optical modelling software (that allows you to view properties such as phase after some evolution)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how accurately you want to do it. The challenge with squeezed states is that both the photon number degrees of freedom and the spatiotemporal degrees of freedom are important. So the question is how to represent such a state in terms of a computer program. Squeezed states (and their spatiotemporal properties) in their most general form are not simply represented by a single function as would be the case for a coherent state. Instead they are represented by kernel functions. What people typically do is to diagonalize the kernel function in terms of some eigenbasis and then represent the state is terms of a matrix representation with a truncated set of these eigenbasis functions. However, it is more accurate to represent the state directly in terms of the kernel function. For the simulation, the kernel function of the state would then be represented on a higher dimensional grid.

Once you have decided how to represent the state, the simulation process can be performed with the aid of unitary transformations applied to the parameterization of the state (matrices of kernel functions). All optical components and free space propagation are represented by unitary transformations. However, when these optical components also introduce a loss, the unitary transform acts like a beamsplitter, where the output from one output port is discarded. So that would be a bit more complicated.

This explanation is a very brief description of a topic that is much more involved. If you have specific questions I can perhaps unpack those aspects a bit more.

Comment: Let's start with, how do you actually express a squeezed state with Kernel functions? So far, I've been modelling them analytically using operators in Klein-Gordon QFT, and I'm not familiar with Kernel functions. Also, do you know if there is an existing publicly available program that does this for us? I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's an existing solution I couldn't find.

Comment: If you want to use an operator approach, then the squeezed state can be represented with the aid of a squeezing operator, but, to represent the spatiotemporal degrees of freedom, you would need to replace the squeezing parameter, with a kernel function. For example: $\xi \hat{a}^2 \rightarrow \hat{a}(k_1)\xi(k_1,k_2)\hat{a}(k_2)$. I prefer a phase space approach where I can represent the state as a Wigner function (or functional). No, I am not award of any software that has been written for this purpose.

Comment: I found a paper that gives a formula for a Kernel Function for a damped squeezed state: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.05990.pdf (Eq. 20). So, if I'm not mistaken, this would be used to create a matrix $ξa^2→a^(k1)ξ(k1,k2)a^(k2)$ like you said in your answer, where I assume a is the squeezing operator (please correct me if I'm wrong). Once we have this matrix...what then? I know you said something about diagonalizing it in terms of an eigenbasis but I'm having trouble figuring out where to go from here.